# Unexpected Behavior from .Net Charts

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, mschart

I am trying to create .Net Chart (Windows.Forms) and export it to a `.jpeg` file.

Below is the code for it

```
public void ExportRouteGraphToJpeg(string nameOfChart, int xMax, int yMax, int xMin, int yMin )
{
    var chartForExport = new Chart();
    chartForExport.Series.Clear();

    var xVsYSeries = new Series
    {
        Name = "XvsY",
        Color = Color.Blue,
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
        IsXValueIndexed = true,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point,
        MarkerSize = 6, 
        MarkerColor   = Color.Blue 
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < xValue.Length; i++)
    {
        xVsYSeries.Points.AddXY(xValue[i], yValue[i]);
    }

    chartForExport.Series.Add(xVsYSeries);

    // Chart Area Definition
    var chartArea = new ChartArea
    {
        Name = "SupportPoints",
        AxisX =
        {
            Title = "X Co-ordinate [cm]",
            ArrowStyle = AxisArrowStyle.Triangle,
            Maximum = xMax + 100,
            Minimum = xMin - 100
        },
        AxisY =
        {
            Title = "Y Co-ordinate [cm]",
            ArrowStyle = AxisArrowStyle.Triangle,
            Maximum = yMax + 100,
            Minimum = yMin - 100
        }
    };

    chartForExport.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
    chartForExport.Location = new Point(0, 50);
    chartForExport.TabIndex = 0;

    chartForExport.Name = "ChartRoute";          

    chartForExport.SaveImage(nameOfChart + ".jpeg", ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

The output I get is shown below (for 5 points of xValue = 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 and same for yValue)

[image]

When I remove `Maximum = yMax + 100, Minimum = yMin - 100` for `AxisX and AxisY`, I get desired output. please see below

[image]

Any suggestion why is this happening?

Comment: does the first output happen only when save to jpg file or shows on form as well?

Comment: @LeiYang I do not use Form, I just use Form assembly for a console application.

Comment: can you give a working sample? `xValue` and `yValue` don't compile, i want to copy and try it.

Comment: @LeiYang, please find the values  ` xValue = new[] {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000};
            yValue = new[] { 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 };
            xMax = xValue.Max();
            yMax = yValue.Max();

            xMin = xValue.Min();
            yMin = yValue.Min();`

Comment: i noticed default `Maximum` and `Minimum` are both NaN

Comment: @LeiYang, can be. But here I assign the max and min. So i do not understand why points are not plotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `IsXValueIndexed = true` from your series definition.

[image]

Comment: Well, the question is not really why it works, but why it breaks the chart. If you look at the [MSDN - IsXValueIndexed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed(v=vs.110).aspx) property documentation, it tells you when you set it to true, it ignores the points X-values and uses its indexes. Also, if you manually set the `Minimum` to 0(zero), you'll see all your points _"Stacked"_, close to X = 0.

Comment: Bottom line is : if you're going to use some property, you should know why you're using and how it affects the chart. The `Chart` object has countless properties within properties, and it is very easy to blow up in your face...:O)

Answer (score -1):

Use some third party charts like high chart,Example is given below

```
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bar Chart</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
              $('#container').highcharts({
                  chart: {
                      type: 'bar'
                  },
                  title: {
                      text: 'MyFruit database info'
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                      categories: ['Records', 'Fragmentation', 'Users']
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                      title: {
                          text: 'Values'
                      }
                  },
                  series: [
                      {
                          name: 'MyFruit_Sites',
                          data: [10, 50, 4]
                      }, {
                          name: 'MyFruit_Devices',
                          data: [500, 80, 3]
                      }
                  ]
              });

              // the button handler
              $('#button').click(function () {
                  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                  chart.addSeries({
                              name: 'MyFruit_Users',
                              data: [30, 60, 4]
                          });
                });
          });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
      <button id="button" class="autocompare">Add series</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, also it is not in c#

Comment: Sorry, but you are not helping here. I am asking a question but you are replying with something you know which is not the answer to the question.